# IOC from outside ServiceStack

Tags: ioc-container, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack with SignalR.
I am trying to access the database orm but my DBFactory.OpenDBConnection is not not being found.

I can do this inside of service stack (ie from an api call) but when I enter via a SignalR hub  IOC is not resolving the factory.

I have found my way to the Apphost container but don't know enough about IOC to be able to create / access the DBFactory.

I have tried doing a container.tryresolve() but it is still null.

(I am away from my desk so the exact code here is off.  Please don't hold that against me as I need to get this working tomorrow.)

TIA